# Bad GRE scores, but otherwise decent application to PhD program. Still worth it?

Tags: phd, gre, political-science

I just finished my MA in Global Affairs, and I am applying to several International Relations PhD programs, one of which is very competitive.
I have a 3.9 GPA, 1 1/2 years of experience in research including an internship at a very respected research center, and very strong LORs. My writing sample was recently accepted to a conference, and I have received great feedback on it otherwise.
However, my GRE scores suck. I took them before I applied to my MA program, and despite studying like crazy for close to 3 months, I bombed. My combined score, converted to the older system is 1020, and I somehow got a 3.5 on the analytical writing section. This last part really shocked me, since writing is one of my strongest skills, and any professor I've had can attest to that. I wanted to retake the test before applying, but my last semester was very hectic and I could not carve out the time to study. Admittedly, I have had very little guidance on the application process, so I told myself that the rest of my application would make up for it. Recently I have begun to worry that this assumption was wrong.

Since I have made it this far in the application process, I am still going to apply. However, I want to have realistic expectations. Am I doomed, or do GRE scores not necessarily make or break a holistic review?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Have considering applying abroad where you might benefit from not needing to report the GRE? If you can go abroad, then you should strongly consider applying to universities where you would not only benefit from being able to show your strongest suit (i.e., all of your grades and achievements rather than GRE) but also facing less competition, cost, and higher probabilities of funding. Let me know if this is an option and, if so, I can add more.